# Android Layout Issue Using axml - In Xamarin

Tags: android

Can anyone see a problem with the code below?

The error is that the id **Title** is not being recognised as a valid id when I try to use it for alignment even though it is created above the reference in the hierarchy.

The warning sign says: *The referenced resource does not exist*.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="150dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:text="aaaaaaa"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/Title"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see anything wrong with your axml file and it worked fine for me in Xamarin.  No errors.  Have you tried a clean build? Sometimes errors in other axml files cause errors in correct files. Try removing both textviews and recompiling. Maybe that will show any other errors.

Comment: @michael_whitley I couldn't find anything so in the end I started again. Oddly, even from a blank project using the tutorial below I get the triangle and the warning even though the formatting is correct. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/relative_layout/

Comment: @Sparked Have you checked for updates lately for your copy of Xamarin or the Android SDK?

Comment: @michael_whitley I have, I'm afraid, and all up to date.